# Iterating Array in Cypress

Tags: arrays, for-loop, cypress

I am pushing Div element in an array and then iterating each one by one, but when I came out of first each section the array length becomes 0 and i am unable to enter into for loop.

in for loop, i want to click a section in each div and perform an assertation and go back to the previous section.

```js
let Array =[]
cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item').each(($pills) => {
    cy.log($pills)
    // cy.log('Success')
    Array.push($pills)
    cy.log(Array.length)

 })
cy.log(Array.length)
   for (const element of Array) {
    cy.wrap(element).click()
    cy.wrap(element).find('.--tag.tag-link.--active.tag-selector-button-link').click()
    var OneOffModel = element.text()
    cy.get('.heading-markdown').contains(OneOffModel)
    cy.go('back')
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach might be to get the count of `.tag-wrapper-item` and loop on that

```js
cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item')
  .its('length')
  .then(count => {
    for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
      cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item').eq(index)
        .click()
      cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item').eq(index)
        .find('.--tag.tag-link.--active.tag-selector-button-link')
        .click()
      cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item').eq(index)
        .invoke('text')
        .then(OneOffModel => {
          cy.get('.heading-markdown').contains(OneOffModel)
        })
      cy.go('back')
    }
  })
```

If you alias each element in the loop, Cypress will try to overcome the detached-from-DOM error when you read the alias

```js
cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item')
  .its('length')
  .then(count => {
    for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {

      cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item').eq(index)
        .as('current')
        .click()

      cy.get('@current')
        .find('.--tag.tag-link.--active.tag-selector-button-link')
        .click()

      cy.get('@current')
        .invoke('text')
        .then(OneOffModel => {
          cy.get('.heading-markdown').contains(OneOffModel)
        })

      cy.go('back')
    }
  })
```

Comment: thank you The guy with the funny name, your second solution worked for me after a little tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

Cypress commands asynchronous, so at the time the Cypress walks through your array, it's not yet been initialized.

To fix this, you can wrap your code with a `then` callback:

```js
let Array =[]
cy.get('.tag-wrapper-item').each(($pills) => {
    cy.log($pills)
    // cy.log('Success')
    Array.push($pills)
    cy.log(Array.length)

 })
cy.then(() => {
   cy.log(Array.length)
   for (const element of Array) {
    cy.wrap(element).click()
    cy.wrap(element).find('.--tag.tag-link.--active.tag-selector-button-link').click()
    var OneOffModel = element.text()
    cy.get('.heading-markdown').contains(OneOffModel)
    cy.go('back')
  } 
})
```

Comment: hi Mikhail thanks, your answer resolved my issue but I am having another problem in this code, when loops go into the second iteration, cypress throws me an error because the div elements become detached from DOM.